# alertdialog listview setMultiChoiceItems

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I created an `AlertDialog` with `ListView`, and the adapter has the CheckAll/UncheckAll elements set programmatically. This works.

But when I'm checking items by touching the screen, then push checkall, then uncheckall, the checked element stays checked.

I have found when the problem occurs. If in function

```
 setMultiChoiceItems(CharSequence[] items, boolean[] checkedItems,
                     DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener listener)
```

I set parameter checkedItems the problem occurs. And if I set checkedItems parameter to null the problem does not occur. Have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Set **checkedItems** to null means no item checked.
checkedItems' array size should be the same with **items**, or error occurs.